# Android: Bypassing 'Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined'

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

trying to get the content from this [site](http://saryelgmal.esy.es/getuser.php) into android text box and this the code I use:

```
utton btngetUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btngetUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        URL hellofileurl = new URL(
                                "http://saryelgmal.esy.es/getuser.php");
                        HttpURLConnection HelloWorldCon = (HttpURLConnection) hellofileurl
                                .openConnection();
                        InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(
                                HelloWorldCon.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader ourstreamreader = new BufferedReader(
                                stream);

                        // buffer for storing file contents in memory
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
                        // for reading one line
                        String line = null;
                        // keep reading till readLine returns null
                        while ((line = ourstreamreader.readLine()) != null) {
                            // keep appending last line read to buffer
                            stringBuffer.append(line);
                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                text.setText(line);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }
    });
```

How ever I Get the error

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined

when trying to use the string line in another function
How to Bypassing this !!

Comment: try making your `line` variable a field of your class...

Comment: @MateusBrandao please explain more , I'm a beginner

Comment: `private String line = null`. Put this in your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is that in JAVA, you cannot access a variable from a method to an anonymous class inside that method unless the variable is declared final inside the method, or the variable is itself global to the parent Class.

Here your variable line is declared in `public void run()` method and you are attempting to use it in the `new Runnable()` anonymous inner class.

Declare your `String line` to be a global variable.

On second thoughts, I think you would rather like to display the `stringBuffer` instead of the `line` as the latter is just just to temporarily read a part of the `ourstreamreader`. So `line` keeps changing but your `stringBuffer` contains the whole contents. Anyways, if you like to display `stringBuffer` instead, on similar logic, declare `stringBuffer` to be global to the Class.

Try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declare the stringBuffer variable to be global here
    StringBuffer stringBuffer;
    String line;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //Inflate layouts and initialise view objects

        //This is from where you posted
        Button btngetUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btngetUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            URL hellofileurl = new URL(
                                    "http://saryelgmal.esy.es/getuser.php");
                            HttpURLConnection HelloWorldCon = (HttpURLConnection) hellofileurl
                                    .openConnection();
                            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(
                                    HelloWorldCon.getInputStream());
                            BufferedReader ourstreamreader = new BufferedReader(
                                    stream);

                            // buffer for storing file contents in memory
                            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
                            // for reading one line
                            line = null;
                            // keep reading till readLine returns null
                            while ((line = ourstreamreader.readLine()) != null) {
                                // keep appending last line read to buffer
                                stringBuffer.append(line);
                            }
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    //Display stringBuffer, not line
                                    text.setText(stringBuffer);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                thread.start();
            }
        });
        //Other things you need to do in onCreate()
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner, please explain more or view code sample

Comment: You are trying to show the entire read page on the textview right?

Comment: Try the solution i posted